# C++ passing overloaded operator() of class as function pointer

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

So I got myself onto shaky ground by insisting on making a C++ class immitate a regular function. The class overloads the function operator, making it a functor, of course. This all works fine, until you want to pass the function pointer of this functor.

Naturally, I want to let the compiler know that we know what we're doing (lol), by doing a reinterpret_cast of this pointer. However, how do I get the address of this particular member function, since it is an overloaded operator. How does one get the address of that?

UPDATE: You asked for an example. Here is a minimal one.

So I have an interface, which I cannot change. It looks like this;

```
typedef void (*some_callback_t)(SomeType);'
void someFunc(some_callback_t);
```

Now, this is quite straight-forward; the API is setting some callback function pointer. So, the idea was to implement the callback as a functor class, by overloading the `operator()`, like so, as usual.

```
class Bah {
  void operator()(SomeType);
};
```

Here comes the question; seeing as I cannot change the API used (the function that expects a function pointer of a certain signature), how can I then get the address of the member function and pass that?

I suspect it goes something like;
`someFunc(reinterpet_cast<some_callback_t>( ? ? ? ));` to make sure that the compiler won't barf at me.

Comment: Do your functors have state?  Do you have to pass by function pointer?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: You typically pass the functor instead of a member function pointer to the `operator()` then your problem(?) does not exist. Please provide a [mcve]. currently it is rather unclear what your problem is

Comment: Depending what you want to do, you may be able to pass your object to a `std::function`.

Comment: Where does the class `Bah` instance come from when you want to execute your call?

Comment: "Naturally, I want to let the compiler know that we know what we're doing (lol), by doing a reinterpret_cast of this pointer."  A reinterpret_cast does the opposite:  it tells the compiler to shut up and close its eyes, you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that you *have* to use a function pointer, and that your functor has no state, you can use a lambda as glue:

```
void takesFunctionPointer(void (*)());

struct MyFunctor {
    void operator()();
};

// ...

takesFunctionPointer([] { return MyFunctor{}(); });
```

Comment: Very neat --- how is it that state prevents this? Could you please explain that?

Comment: @CasperB.Hansen because, if you needed to pass state for `MyFunctor` into `takesFunctionPointer`, you'd have no channel through which to do so. Such a channel is what is provided by C-style functions that take both a `void (*function)(void *)` and a `void *userdata`, only to give it back to your function upon calling. In the specific case above, the lambda just default-constructs a `MyFunctor` on the fly to call it.

Comment: I see. I've never played with lambdas in C++, so this answer was interesting! The functor keeps a reference to it's owner, which it is supposed to inform once called.

Comment: @CasperB.Hansen in that case it gets hairy -- you need to pass your state through a global (optionally `thread_local`) variable. But beware of reentrancy!

Answer (score 2):

> How does one get the address of that?

In the same way as any other member function. The name of the function is `class_name::operator()`. An example:

```
struct class_name {
    void operator()(){}
};

void (class_name::*member_function_pointer)() = &class_name::operator();
class_name instance;
(instance.*member_function_pointer)(); // in a block scope
```

> Naturally, I want to let the compiler know that we know what we're doing (lol), by doing a reinterpret_cast of this pointer.

That's usually not what one would want to do.